# How to set white pixels to transparent using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

My code so far. I want to crop out the white in the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg')
image2 = np.ones((255, 255, 4))
for i in range(255):
    for j in range(255):
        if image[i,j,0] == 255: 
            image2[i, j, :] = np.append(image[i, j, :], 1)
        else:
            image2[i, j, :] = np.append(image[i, j, :], 1)

cv2.imwrite('image2.png', image2)
```

But it just produces an empty plot.

Comment: 'making an image transparent' is not the same as 'cropping out the white'. Can you explain what you want to achieve exactly, preferably with an input and output image?

Comment: I would Like all the white parts of the image to be transparent in the output image.

Comment: At first share a sample input and output image here. Besides your both conditional statement are the same -> image2[i,j,:]=np.append(image[i,j,:],1).

Answer (score 4):

This should be enough:

> The background of the website is white, so **"right click" the Output** and "open image in new tab" and you'll see that it is *transparent* :)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
image_bgr = cv2.imread('image_bgr.png')
# get the image dimensions (height, width and channels)
h, w, c = image_bgr.shape
# append Alpha channel -- required for BGRA (Blue, Green, Red, Alpha)
image_bgra = np.concatenate([image_bgr, np.full((h, w, 1), 255, dtype=np.uint8)], axis=-1)
# create a mask where white pixels ([255, 255, 255]) are True
white = np.all(image_bgr == [255, 255, 255], axis=-1)
# change the values of Alpha to 0 for all the white pixels
image_bgra[white, -1] = 0
# save the image
cv2.imwrite('image_bgra.png', image_bgra)
```

> - **Input**:

[image: Input]

> - **Output** ("right click" >> "open in new tab"):

[image: Output]